# how to load xib view in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I want to define a custom table cell view and reuse it in many `tableView`, so I create a xib file containing my `custom cell view`, but the problem is I don't know how to load the xib file in storyboard

the table cell view:

[image]

and I want the view show in the black area in storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just build the view directly in the storyboard prototype cells : http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/

And to use the same view in different tableviews present in different controllers, you can just copy and paste (cmd-C cmd-V) the view within the prototype cell, so you dont need the XIB's at all.

But using the assistant editor, you an drag or copy-paste the views from the XIB to the storyboard too (but thats not recommended)

Hope this helps

Comment: but if I need to change a cell, I need to change many cell for different view controller

Comment: in that case, you should create a single xib, and load the view from the xib, programmatically in all the controllers. You'll have to avoid using the storyboard for the custom UITableCell view